# Unable to load multiple WordPress websites on external php file

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

We are hosting multiple websites on a single server where I want to load all websites plugin on an external PHP file. I'm reading all websites Url and hosting directory path from host config file. And running PHP `foreach` where I'm passing require(wp-load.php) for each website but its loading only first websites and the plugin list shows is for first website only. I'm fetching plugins from get_plugins() function.

This is for AWS server and using PHP, MySql.

```
class Plugininfo{
 function EachSiteData($home_url,$abspath){
  if (is_file($abspath."/wordpress/wp-load.php")){
   define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
   require_once($abspath."/wordpress/wp-load.php"); //Here it load only first website I tried to echo home url but it shows only first websites url.
   if ( ! function_exists( 'get_plugins' ) ) {
        $pluginfile_path= $abspath.'/wordpress/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php';
        require_once $pluginfile_path;
   }
   $all_plugins=array();
   $all_plugins = get_plugins();
   foreach($all_plugins as $url => $plugins){
    //Code to list all websites // currently its showing for first website
   }
 } //close function
}//close class

$server; //Is an array where I'm storing website's url in key and host path in value.

foreach ($servers as $key => $value) { //Creating object for each website
  $PlugininfoObject= new Plugininfo();
  $eachsite_data=$PlugininfoObject->EachSiteData($key,$value);
  $PlugininfoObject->DatabaseOperations($eachsite_data[0],$eachsite_data[1]);
  $PlugininfoObject->destroy();
  unset($PlugininfoObject);
}
```

//Problem is it is loading only first website not which are present in last foreach loop.

Expected result: It will load all wordpress and give all websites plugin list with their status. All websites are on single server only.

Comment: _“where I'm passing require(wp-load.php) for each website”_ - I don’t think it will work that way. Even if you are requiring the “different” wp-load files from the different websites, it still all runs within the scope of your main script. The first thing wp-load does, is define the `ABSPATH` constant - if it is not defined already, which it will be here though, after you embedded it for the first time. So the absolute path used to require further files internally will always be that of the first site.

Comment: @04FS “where I'm passing require(wp-load.php) for each website” I written this for is for understanding,please check the code.

I tried with ABSPATH as well and the result is same.

Comment: Do you mean multiple Wordpress website but you want single plugin directory for all of them and this plugins should be loaded by a php file containing function get_plugin  this not right practical steps.. Wordpress sites can share database but files and directories is confusing.

Comment: e.g: we are hosting abc.com and xyz.com on our aws server. we are managing their entry in hostfile(Host path and hosting folder).
I'm reading that file and storing it in array($server) and I'm running that array in foreach. but it shows plugin listing for abc.com only. Unable to load second websites(xyz.com) plugin listing.